# Rails 3 bundle permissions problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error message from Passenger:

> Permission denied -
>   /root/.bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications/activeresource-3.0.0.beta2.gemspec

Does anyone recognize it and can tell me how I can find a solution? I'm really stuck…

The server runs Ubuntu 9.

ps. The problem occured after I ran a deploy in which I'd added to the Gemfil **gem "rails", "3.0.0.beta2"** ds.

Answer (score 4):

Bundle install, by default on Ubuntu, tries to install in a .bundle directory (in this case `/root/.bundle`.

Passenger (which runs under Apache as the `www-data` user) can't read your `/root` directory.

Instead, in your app, bundle it like this:

```
bundle install .bundle
```

This allows passenger to find the gems. Also make sure you chown your source tree for www-data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I did a bundle install vendor/gems instead and this seems to have done the trick!